# Manipulate Querystring in Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a site that I support which is a mixture of classic ASP and ASP.NET.  My goal is to encrypt the querystring in a manner that is transparent to the user.  On the ASP.NET side I am using a approach similar to what Mads Kristensen has put together here:   http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx

My problem is how can I replicate this on the classic ASP side?  The HttpModule wont work for classic ASP as those requests are handled outside of the ASP.NET page life cycle so I have been looking at handling this in the Global.asa with no luck so far.  To replicate the httpmodule I would need to get a hold of the HttpContext and I havent found a vbscript equivalent.  I am a bit stuck any assistance or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mads Kristensen is using Rijndael cipher (AES) in his encrypt and decrypt functions, so you need to recreate these functions again in classic ASP. The following pages could help you :

Short tutorial on using AES is VBScript: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/AesIv.asp
The module can be found at: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatCrypt2Ref.html

**But**, you could also expose the "QueryStringModule.cs" class as a COM object and dispose this to your classic ASP page.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx

Comment: ChiYoung thank you for the great suggestion definitely on the right track.  I am new to classic asp.  The issue I am now bumping into is how do I get ahold of the HttpContext.Current for the ASP page from the looks of things I am going to need to pass it in however I am not sure what the classic ASP equivalent is.